Writing to qemu RISCV UART using c
I made a helloworld program on RISC-V qemu using the UART using https://popovicu.com/posts/bare-metal-programming-risc-v/ Uros Popovicu's guide in RISC-V assembly. I was wondering how I could write to the UART using c and RISC-V qemu.
I tried :
#define UART_TX 0x10000000  

void _start() {
    char *str = "Hello, World!\n";
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        *(volatile char*)UART_TX = str[i];
    }

    while (1);
}

I tried compiling the c code :
riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -S -o hello.s hello.c
riscv64-linux-gnu-as -march=rv64i -mabi=lp64 -o hello.o -c hello.s

to RISC-V and using the same linker file as in popovicu's example :
 riscv64-linux-gnu-ld -T linker.ld --no-dynamic-linker -m elf64lriscv -static -nostdlib -s -o hello hello.o

using the following linker file (with only some slight modifications) :
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY {
  dram_space (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 1024
}

SECTIONS {
  .text : {
    hello.o(.text.bios)
  } > dram_space
}

And running it using :
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios hello

This results in nothing being print. Is this the correct way to access the UART or does my error lie elsewhere? Thanks in advance.

No matter system you have to configure the UART before you can use it.

@Lundin can you give some example code?

That would be highly system-specific and I don't know your system. But essentially you have to configure baudrate, stop and parity bits, number of data bits, error handling, hardware handshaking and so on. Under Linux there's for example the termios library which covers all of this.

I am a little confused by this because in assembly you can just : .global _start
.section .text.bios
_start: addi a0, x0, 0x68
li a1, 0x10000000
sb a0, (a1) # 'h'
addi a0, x0, 0x65
sb a0, (a1) # 'e'
addi a0, x0, 0x6C
sb a0, (a1) # 'l'
addi a0, x0, 0x6C
sb a0, (a1) # 'l'
addi a0, x0, 0x6F
sb a0, (a1) # 'o'
loop: j loop . Can you explain why I cant to something similar in c. If you want any system details check popovicu's tutorial.

I'm not going to decipher that, but this has nothing to do with programming but hardware. For any hardware to work as expected, it must first be initialized through drivers or memory-mapped registers. In some cases it might use default values though, so maybe that's what you have here. It's pretty senseless for an UART to have that though, since there isn't really a communication standard for it. "9600 8-N-1" might be the closest thing to that I guess.

The primary issue you have is that you're not properly setting up an environment that C can use. A _start symbol will generally always be in assembly.
In particular, using GDB to attach to QEMU, I see that the stack pointer sp will still have a default 0x0 value. The C code relies on the stack being in valid memory, and the system crashes on the second instruction of your program when it tries to write to an area on the stack.
With the -bios QEMU flag, you're saying that you will do all of the setup work (beyond a few instructions that load the HART ID into a0 then jump to your code.) You need to start in assembly, set up a usable environment (including loading registers with the required values,) then you can jump to you C code.

As a side note, everything is in the .text.bios section, in the assembly program in the article that you link to. This isn't the case with the C program, where you should use a less minimal linker script. While the correct sections are being linked in, hello.o(.text.bios) isn't doing what you think it is here.

Thx! So essentially write a second stage bootloader, Who fixes the stack and jumps into the main c program. I shoudl also fix my linker file for rotodata etc.

@JipHelsen Yes, though it wouldn't be a second-stage bootloader, this is very much first-stage or earlier. With the -bios options, you're saying that you're providing the firmware for the system, you manage everything. Instead of it being like writing the OS kernel, or even a bootloader, by using -bios you say that you're writing the lowest-level boot-up system code.

Ah okay thx, zsbl is ofc zero stage haha as in the name.

The other common thing people forget they need to do before jumping to C code is to enable the FPU -- if the C compiler is compiling code that assumes presence of the FPU, the guest code will crash when it first uses an FP insn. (At least, this is necessary for Arm; I'm not sure for RISCV, but it's certainly on the list of things to check.)
